# How can I stop OS X Lion from reopening multiple terminal windows?

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app

How can I stop OS X Lion from reopening multiple terminal windows when I relaunch Terminal.app? When I launch terminal, two windows spawn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enter the following in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

This disables Lion's resume feature for Terminal only.

---

If you want to disable resuming application "document" windows globally, go to *System Preferences » General » Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps*:

[image]